# Using python to count number of comment lines and comment blocks in python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, comments

Currently I'm trying to create a python script that counts the number of comment lines and comment blocks in that are in a python file.

I've tried using regular expression but that didn't work out. Now I'm just using regular for's and if's to figure it out. Right now I'm trying to figure out how many comment lines are in a block and subtracting that with total number of comment lines in the file to get the amount of single line comments.

```
it = iter(lines) # lines is a list that contains all the lines that are in the file
for each_ in lines:
    each_ = each_.strip()
    if each_.startswith('#'): # If a line starts with a '#' move to the next line
        next(it)
        print(each_)
        if each_.startswith('#') is True: # If the next line starts with a '#' increment d 
            d += 1 # d is the value for: Comment lines in a block
```

Example python file:

```
# a
# b
# c
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
    # d
# e
f
```

The expected output is:

Comment blocks = 1 (how many times more than one # appear on the next line in the same orientation [a,b,c are part of 1 comment block, while d,e are not a comment block])

Comment lines in a block = 3

Single line comments = 2

Comment: I can see why a,b,c are a block, can you explain why d&e are not? Any whitespace creates a new block? what if d&e add only one space each..

Comment: @NicLaforge d&e are not comment blocks because they don't start in the same orientation (for d the '#' is at the beginning but for e the '#' there is whitespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this code:

```
single_lines = []
blocks = []
block = []
block_position = 0
for line in lines.splitlines():
    try:
        position = line.index('#')  # Find the index of the first #
    except ValueError:
        position = -1
    line = line.lstrip()
    if line.startswith('#'):
        # If current block position match the new one
        if block_position == position:
            # Part of the same block, adding to the list
            block.append(line)
        else:
            # adding the previous block
            if len(block) > 0:
                if len(block) == 1:
                    single_lines.append(block)
                else:
                    blocks.append(block)
            # Starting a new block
            block = [line]
            block_position = position
    else:
        # Means that there is no # in the line
        if len(block) > 0:
            # If block was not empty we are closing it
            if len(block) == 1:
                single_lines.append(block)
            else:
                blocks.append(block)
            block_position = 0
            block = []
else:
    # Validation if at the end of the loop we still have a block that was not closed
    if len(block) > 0:
        if len(block) == 1:
            single_lines.append(block)
        else:
            blocks.append(block)
```

Print formatting Solution:

```
print('Total of Blocks: {}'.format(len(blocks)))
print('Total of single lines: {}'.format(len(single_lines)))
for idx, block in enumerate(blocks):
    print('Block {} - contains {} lines :\n{}'.format(idx, len(block), '\n'.join(block)))
```

**Input 1**:

```
# a
# b
# c
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
    # d
# e
f
```

**Output 1**:

```
[['# a', '# b', '# c'], ['# d'], ['# e']]
```

**Input 2:**

```
# a
# b
# c
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
    # d
    # e
# f
f
# g
# h
```

**Output 2:**

```
[['# a', '# b', '# c'], ['# d', '# e'], ['# f'], ['# g', '# h']]
```

**Output 2: with formatting:**

```
Total of Blocks: 3
Total of single lines: 1
Block 0 - contains 3 lines :
# a
# b
# c
Block 1 - contains 2 lines :
# d
# e
Block 2 - contains 2 lines :
# g
# h
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much! Any idea on how to print the number of blocks and lines within blocks instead?

Comment: I have added a way to do it (code modified to make it easier). But as far as the formatting the ```blocks and single_lines``` provide you the result of the file. You can print the result anyway you like.

Comment: I was playing around with it, and I found that if I changed the parts for where Line 2 and Line 3 are to: # Line 2 (now an empty line in the middle) # Line 3, it puts the two of them in to a comment block even though they aren't a comment block due to the empty line between them. Do you know what the workaround for this would be?

Comment: There was a typo in the code (updated), can you retry your case and let me know.